# Connecting to Raspberry Pi via mac over USB ethernet adapter - Self assigned IP

Tags: ssh, mac, raspbian

I have both a Mac and a Raspberry Pi, my goal is to be able to ssh into the Pi from my Mac via an ethernet cable. I bought a USB to Ethernet adapter and connected the two but havent had any luck detecting the device with nmap or anything else. The adapter does show up in my Mac settings, but it displays as having a "Self-assigned IP." How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Can you check if that adapter is supported in RPi or it is shown in `dmesg`? Did you try to set a static IP address both in RPi and mac?

Comment: @Biswapriyo I was originally SSH'ing to it via it's set hostname on my home WiFi network, which worked fine. Why would it matter if the adapter is supported in RPi if it is only connected to the mac? I am currently on a school network so cant set a static IP for my mac, although I would like this to work off of a network as well.

Comment: Strong guess - Your devicees are currently using DHCP to get a Mac address, but when you are connecting to the pi  you are not connecting it to the router(which has a dhcp server). Assigning static IPs in the same subnet (which should be a different one to the WiFi one) to the ethernet will bypass this issue. Another solution might be to ditch the direct connection and plug the pi into the router, which will make it discoverable to the MAC across its wifi connection

Comment: @davidgo To clarify, I want to be a be able just plug directly into the pi via Ethernet on public networks and share my laptops WiFi connection so that I can work on it in class. In this scenario, I can’t plug the Pi into a router. How do I configure static IP’s on this adapters subnet?

Comment: Can't help with specifics (I don't use MACs or Pi's, but do know networking at this level - hence comment not answer) Try googling setting static IP on X where X us Mac or Pi. If your main address range is 192.168... try assign IPs in 172.16.1.x subnet 255.255.255.0 - Once thus is working you will need to get NAT working on the MAC.

Comment: I think you got me on the right track but I wont be able to test this stuff out until I have the chance to interface with the Pi directly later today. I'll post an answer if I figure it out, thanks for helping @davidgo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this was actually ridiculously easy, not sure why no articles ever mentioned it. Instead of setting up a subnet static IP, Just ssh like this:

`ssh pi@raspberrypi.local`

Thats it... wild.

Comment: This is mdns aka Zeroconf, look it up